# I am trying to have javascript replace data from a JSON file in an HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, json

JSON {"benefits": [
        {
            "title": "Free",
            "description": "Members receive free shipping"
        },
        {
            "title": "Delivery",
            "description": "Your ride will always be in delivered"
        },
        {
            "title": "News",
            "description": "A Bi-Weekly newsletter"
        }
    ]
    }

JAVASCRIPT

```
var benefitsVar = document.getElementById("memberBenefits");
or (var l=0; l < dataPull.benefits.length; l++){

benefitsVar[l].getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML = 
dataPull.benefits[l].title;
benefitsVar[l].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = 
dataPull.benefits[l].description;

};
```

HTML

```
<section id="memberBenefits">

<ul>
  <li > <h4 class="benefits">Lorem Ipsum</h4></li>
 <li> <p class="benefits">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </p></li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li> <h4 class="benefits">Lorem Ipsum</h4></li>
<li><p class="benefits">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </p></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li> <h4 class="benefits">Lorem Ipsum</h4></li>
    <li ><p class="benefits">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </p></li>

</ul></section>
```

Comment: Have posted answer helps you? If not then expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it using ajax :

Note : I don't understand why you don't want to use jquery.It won't harm if you use jquery. Use jquery for the ajax thing and use javascript for the other things :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/data.json',
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: 'json',             
    success: function(data){
    var newData = '';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<benefits.length; i++){
     newData +='<ul>'+
    '<li > <h4 class="benefits">'+benefits[i].title+'</h4></li>'+
    '<li ><p class="benefits">'+benefits[i].description+' </p></li>'+
    '</ul>';

    }
$('#memberBenefits').html(newData);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('Could not get Data from the file');
    }
});
```

Your html :

```
<section id="memberBenefits">


</section>
```

Comment: I need to do this in javascript.   I can't use jquery.

Comment: What I had that actually worked was the following, but it did not actually replace the data, it only appended it.                                                                                   
 newData = '';  for (var i=0; i < benefits.length; i++){
newData += '<h4>'+benefits[l].title+'</h4>';
newData += '<p>'+benefits[l].description+'</p>';
}
var element = document.querySelector('#memberBenefits li');
element.innerHTML = newData;
}

Comment: check my updated answer for doing it with javascript

Comment: I think it's totally fine to ask the user to accept and upvote the answer if the answer actually works for him :)

Comment: Im sorry, the answer did not work for me.  I'm actually using ajax to pull data from a json file.  I can not use jquery.  What I had originally was                        
           newData = ''; for (var i=0; i < benefits.length; i++){ newData += '<h4>'+benefits[l].title+'</h4>'; newData += '<p>'+benefits[l].description+'</p>'; } var element = document.querySelector('#memberBenefits li'); element.innerHTML = newData; }

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe that will work...!  Thank you...!

Comment: check the updated answer for ajax. you should always mention what you have and what you have tried so far in the question description to get the proper answer.